# How to remove the Spaces in this case

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically building HTML in javascript .

This is the sample HTML Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cust_area = 'MYAREA'
    var cust_phone = '908988888'
    var cust_street_name = 'MYSTREET'
    var cust_name = 'SOMENAME'
    var cust_state = 'MYSTATE'
    var cust_locality = 'MYLOCALITY'
    var cust_city = 'MYCITY'
    var cust_building_no = 'MYBUILDING'

    var custaddresshtml = '<p>' + cust_name + ', +91-' + cust_phone + '</p>\
                             <p>'+ cust_street_name + '<br></p>\
                              <p>'+ cust_building_no + '<br>\
                            '+ cust_locality + ',' + cust_area + '<br>\
                            ' + cust_city + ',' + cust_state + '<br>\
                            </p>';
    $(".custmerAdres").html(custaddresshtml);
});
```

When ran the jsfiddle , could you please tell me why the space is coming after the phone number and street number ??

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2345/)

Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue ??

Comment: `<p>` elements have vertical margins. Restyling them with CSS (or using `<br>` elements as line breaks instead) would solve your problem.

Comment: because you set a `1em` margin on `<p/>` elements

Comment: because of this `margin: 1em 0 0`

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the style

```
p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

> **It will be gone if you remove the style for `<p>`**

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2347/)**

Answer (score 1):

The space is being caused by the following CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

There's a margin being applied to the paragraph and as you have a closing of p tags after the phone number and before the street name, this is being applied to the paragraph for the street name.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you have

```
p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

Remove it and it'll work.